# module_load_include not working

Tags: 7

I've been looking on several sites trying to figure this out, but no dice yet.

I have a module, 'spower'. I need to include several php files inside the polygon folder (spower/polygon/***.php). In the spower.module file, I've included the line:

module_load_include('php', 'spower', 'polygon/polygonBase');

However, when I run the module, I get the error `Call to undefined function PolygonBase`, so obviously, something's not loading right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to load

```
sites/all/modules/custom/spower/polygon/polygonBase.php
```

then

```
module_load_include('php', 'spower', 'polygon/polygonBase');
```

should work fine.

- Make sure the file `polygonBase.php` is readable by the webserver user.
- Make sure `module_load_include` is added for processing prior to using functions in that file.

Comment: It was a permission problem :$ Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In order to debug whether module_load_include() is working or not, you can check the return value using code as

```
$file_path = module_load_include('php', 'spower', 'polygon/polygonBase');

if ($file_path === FALSE) {
  dpm('Failed to include: ' . $filename);
}
else {
  dpm('Successfully included: ' . $file_path);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting the message `failed to include: filename`;